# Search string by first letters using NavigableSet/SortedSet interfaces only

Tags: java, search, tree, set

I have a:

```
String s = "ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE + "cd";
```

Let's put it into `TreeSet<String> treeSet`.
Now I have to find this string using first 3 chars `"ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE`.
Method `treeSet.sublist("ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE, true, "ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE, true)` doesn't work for me. Is there any way to make it work? I can't change the last char of query to char + 1, because of character overflow.

Comment: @whoever voted for closing, I believe this question includes the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. It’s clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concrete answer is easy, you probably have figured this out already:

```
treeSet.subSet("ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE, "ac")
```

(this is the same as `treeSet.subSet("ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE, true, "ac", false)`).

Given you receive the three chars in a variable (typically a `String`), that may be easier said than done. If your string ends in `Character.MAX_VALUE`, you will need to chop off all trailing `Character.MAX_VALUE` and then increment the last remaining character. And then there’s still a special case: if your string consists of all `Character.MAX_VALUE`, you will need to use `tailSet()` instead of `subSet()`. With some `if` statements and a loop it can all be programmed. Happy coding.

An easier option: Always use `tailSet()`. This is guaranteed to include the string if it is there. Take the first string from the tail set and check if it begins with you three characters. If it does, you have found a string that satisfies your search condition. If either the tail set is empty or the first string doesn’t start with your three chars, your string wasn’t there, cannot be found.

Comment: 1. what will be the solution for `"ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE` query??

Comment: 2. `tailSet("ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE, true)` returns every element after `ab+character.max_value`. like "New York", "Canada" and others.

Comment: 3. what if I'll have `Character.MAX_VALUE+"b"` element in treeset. how to find it with `Character.MAX_VALUE` query?

Comment: 1. `treeSet.subSet("ab" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE, "ac")`. 2. That’s true. If you want all strings that start with the query string, the tail set doesn’t do all the filtering necessary. 3. `tailSet("" + Character.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me